# android.support.v4.app.Fragment: undefined method getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-nested-fragment

I'm using `ActionBarSherlock` and `ViewPageIndicator` and I tried to implement nested fragments, but the method `getChildFragmentManager()` is undefined in my`android.support.v4.app.Fragments`.

There are no other errors and ABS and VPI work as expected.

I'm not using the Support Library v13, I'm on the latest versions and I've cleaned my projects. A normal `android.app.Fragment` does not complain about `getChildFragmentManager()`.

I also tried rearranging the support library dependencies (android-support-v4.jar in ABS, VPI and main project referencing it, or android-support-v4.jar in as external jar), but `getChildFragmentManager()` remains undefined.

If I remove the VPI though, `getChildFragmentManager()` works, but of course VPI stops working. So, there must be something wrong with the dependencies, but I'm running out of ideas to try.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you get rid of android-support-v4 everywhere, and use only v13?

Comment: try to download the latest android-support-v4.jar with the Android SDK Manager and then copy the jar from `<sdkdir>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` to your project and also to ABS and VPI (afaik both have a older copy of android-support-v4.jar in thier download) i had some similar issues with the support library because of diffrent versions in ABS and in my project (but not using VPI)

Comment: @Dodge I had downloaded the latest version for my main project (or at least I thought I had!) and was using that as external jar for ABS and VPI, but I tried downloading it again anyways and voilá, problem solved (or rather, one problem replaced with others, but progress!). If you add your solution as answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i had some similar issues with the support library because of diffrent versions in ABS and in my project (but not using VPI)

try to download the latest android-support-v4.jar with the Android SDK Manager and then copy the jar from `<sdkdir>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` to your project and also to ABS and VPI (afaik both have a older copy of android-support-v4.jar in thier download)

Comment: Getting the latest version of android-support-v4.jar worked. I just downloaded VPI source once more, and copied its support library. But i guess it was an old version. Thanks!

Comment: What is ABS and VPI`?

Comment: ABS: ActionBarSherlock / VPI: ViewPageIndicator

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The file date on the one in my project was 9/13 and the one in my /extras/android/support/v4/ directory was 7/13. Replacing the file fixed my issues.