# How to my map FragmentActivity with Maps inside dialog

Tags: android, dialog, maps

Tried almost all the ways to put `maps` `FragmentActivity` inside `dialog` cannot able to succeed that.
 here is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
private GoogleMap mMap;

LatLng latLng;
String userName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        latLng = (LatLng) getIntent().getExtras().get(MainActivity.MAP_COORDINATES);
        userName = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(MainActivity.USER_NAME);
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            }, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(userName));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            onMapReady(mMap);
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

}

i want to put above `FragmentActivity` inside `Dialog` (it is possible to pass `fragment` but i don't find a way to pass `FragmentActivity` tell me if any)

Here is the code `i tried in different way` but no use it is throws `null pointer exception`

```
private Dialog showMaps(Context context, final LatLng latLng, final String username){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    MapView mapView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    mapView.onCreate(dialog.onSaveInstanceState());
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(username));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));
        }
    });

    Window window = getWindow();
    assert window != null;
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: use MapView instead

Comment: can you give some code how i can acheive that

Comment: https://inducesmile.com/android/android-mapview-example-tutorial/

Comment: I did n't find a attribute called `map.getMap();`

Comment: Even im using the same but null pointer exception 
instead of getMap() i'm usign getMapAsync() now there is no method called getMap()

Comment: You are using both. Either use map fragment or map view

Comment: can you help me with that i want to pass `name` and `latlng` details.
can you help me with code

Comment: First describe what you want to achieve then only I can help

Comment: when i click on location in profile activity (which contain all the details of user) it should show a dialog which contains map 
In that i want place a marker related to location of user and name of the user in snippet

Comment: So you don't need a map activity only dialog is enough

Comment: help me how can i do that i try some earlier it showing dialog with maps but entire screen background turns black even dialog is dismissed

Comment: given you the link for that already try implementing using that

Comment: it is giving black background even dialog got dimissed

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: 
  Instead going for map fragments in dialog, just use FrameLayout as parent and add map fragment as a last child of the layout and make its visibility to gone(flexibility here is you can specify the size of the map fragment, but coming to dialog it is too complex)..So whenever the user clicks on some button, you can make it visible programatically like...

```
 mapFragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and

```
mapFragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: my requirement is to put in dialog

Comment: 9
down vote
accepted
The answer (thanks to @Luksprog) is using the getChildFragmentManager instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager

It wasn't available for me, cause I had to upgrade my support-v4 jar, as described here: android.support.v4.app.Fragment: undefined method getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298052/adding-a-fragment-to-a-dialog