# getChildFragmentManager() method is undefined

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have the same issue has this post: [android.support.v4.app.Fragment: undefined method getChildFragmentManager()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805574/android-support-v4-app-fragment-undefined-method-getchildfragmentmanager). I need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` because I'm using nested fragments.

My problem is: the solution in the other post does not work for me:

- My SDK is updated.
- I got my android-support-v4 from the SDK folder.
- I added android-support-v4 both the my project and ABS.

Here is my libs:

[image]

How can I correctly use this method?

Comment: check this too...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945904/the-method-getchildfragmentmanager-is-undefined

Comment: And i think your are trying to use it for android API level less than 17 and the method `getChildFragmentManager()` is only for API 17 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've resolved your issue yet, but I was having the same issue and I resolved it.  The getCildFragmentManager() method is a method of the class Fragment and not FragmentActivity.  Just because your class extends fragment activity does not mean you'll have access to this method.  What I did is I created an instance of my fragment in which I wanted to place the child fragment and invoked the method through that fragment instance.  There are obviously other approaches to this, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something in your android manifest, look at the header or 'footer of your android manifest about minimum SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by using old android.support.v4.

once you change the latest library.it will solved
I solved it by change it.
Hope it will work